# How can I show that the following ODE has global semi-solutions (i.e, defined for all t > 0):

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\dot{x}=4y^3+2x$

$\dot{y}=-4x^3-2y-\cos{x}$

Do I have to prove that the solution is Lipschitz so that it doesn't grow to infinity in an interval or is that a way to solve the system, which gives me the explicit solution and then i see that it's well defined for all t>0? How can i proceed?

Comment: The [streamplot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=-1526&y=-71&i=streamplot%5B%7B4*y%5E3%2B2*x,-4*x%5E3-2*y-cos(x)%7D,+%7Bx,-10,10%7D,+%7By,-10,10%7D%5D) suggests that there is a first integral, or nearly one. One could try $V=x^4+\sin(x)+y^4$ so that $$\dot V=(4x^3+\cos x)\dot x+4y^3\dot y=8x^4+2x\cos x-8y^4$$ but that is still not quite right.

Comment: But as $\dot V<9V$ for $x$ large enough, one gets an exponentially controlled upper bound for the possible growth of the solution, which guarantees the existence of the solution for all $t>0$.